# How to output in different directory?

Tags: python

I have this:

```
from os import path
base_path = "C:\\texts\\*.txt"
for file in files:
   with open (file) as in_file, open(path.join(base_path,"%s_tokenized.txt" % file),   "w") as out_file:
       data = in_file.readlines()
       for line in data:
           words = line.split()
           str1 = ','.join(words)
           out_file.write(str1)
           out_file.write("\n")
```

It produced tokenized files in the same directory it reads from. How can I output those out_files in different directory such as `"C:\\texts\\Tokenized"` ?

I know there are some ways to move those new files to other directory after producing them, but what I wanna know is that if there is anyway to output new files to other directory at the same time they are produced in above code?

Comment: BTW, there's no need to use `readlines`. Just iterate over the input file directly: `for line in in_file:`.

Comment: ... Use a different base path?

Comment: @FMc I need to first make a list and then split words of each line separately

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams so from where it can read the files?

Comment: @MACEE No, you don't need to first make a list (in `data`); you can skip that part. Opened files can be iterated over directly, line by line. Give it a try. :)

Comment: @FMc I tried it before, but I can't produce each line's tokens separately. It just output one token in each line: ` for line in in_file:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
     out_file.write(word)
     out_file.write("\n")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
import os
import glob
source_pattern = 'c:/texts/*.txt'
output_directory = 'c:/texts/tokenized'

# Iterate over files matching source_pattern
for input_file in glob.glob(source_pattern):

    # build the output filename
    base,ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(input_file))
    output_file = os.path.join(output_directory,base + '_tokenized' + ext)

    with open(input_file) as in_file, open(output_file,'w') as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            out_file.write(','.join(line.split()) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I output to files in arbitrary directories :

```
dir_name = "../some_dir"
if not os.path.exists(dir_name) : os.makedirs(dir_name)
out_file_name = dir_name + '/out.txt'
out_file = open( out_file_name, 'w')
```

EDIT :

```
file_name = "{0}_tokenized.txt".format(something_from_tokenizing)
if not os.path.exists(dir_name) : os.makedirs(dir_name)
out_file_name = dir_name + file_name
```

EDIT :

I just tried it, worked for me. You simply need two paths, one for the source directory and one for the destination. Hope this helps.

```
import os
from os import path
f1 = open("in.txt")
f2 = open("out.txt")
files = ["in.txt", "out.txt"]
base_path = "."
dir_name = "./some_dir"
if not os.path.exists(dir_name) : os.makedirs(dir_name)
for file in files:
   with open (file) as in_file, open(path.join(dir_name,"%s_tokenized.txt" % file),   "w") as out_file:
       data = in_file.readlines()
       for line in data:
           words = line.split()
           str1 = ','.join(words)
           out_file.write(str1)
           out_file.write("\n")
```

Comment: if it is one file, it'ok but I am dealing with a number of text files together. I read them from one directory and tokenized them, then save tokenized files with the same name of each files + tokenized.txt in the same directory....instead of doing that I want to directly write them to another directory

Comment: do you have a criteria for naming the output files and/or directories ?

Comment: tokenized files have the same name as the source file + tokenized.txt `($file_name)_tokenized.txt`

Comment: hmm I don't have problem with naming the tokenized files.. I did it `path.join(base_path,"%s_tokenized.txt" % file)`. my problem is the above code produces tokenized file in the same directory as the source files exists. I want to output (write) the new files in different directory

Comment: I think what makes it difficult is I am dealing with a number of files at the same time and also I use source files' name to name the output files!

Comment: I have 300 text files in one directory. I read them together, tokenized each file, for each file produce another file with the same name follwed by `_tokenized.txt` . These are my output files which I want to save them in another directory

Comment: Actually I create files with same name and some suffix, I just want to save them in another directory. That's my problem.

Comment: you simply need to use another path for the destintion directory. see my latest edit. cheers.

Comment: Thanks I tried it, but it again produce the new files in the same directory